# How to make all Symfony DI services public?

Tags: php, symfony, testing, dependency-injection, symfony5

In our integration tests, we need to get/set a few services, so need them to be public.

What we currently do is configure every such service this way:

```
App\Infrastructure\Mail\Transport\SenderInterface:
    public: '%services_are_public%'
```

And our `test` environment is configured as such:

```
parameters:
    services_are_public: true
```

Is there a way to make all services public by default instead, in a given environment?

Comment: You can just add public: true to the _defaults sections of your services.yaml files.  But you really should be asking why you need all these services public just for testing.  You should also be looking at how environment specific services.yaml files are loaded.  There should not be a need for parameters like service_are_public.

Comment: There is no need, since 4.1 [there is a way to fetch private services from the container](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing) in the `test` environment.

Comment: @yivi Sorry, not yet, hopefully this week!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase` or `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase` (which you probably should, for functional/integration testing), there is no need to make services public.

These classes include a simple method to get a "special" container that is able to get private services directly:

```
$container = static::$container;
```

This has been the case [since Symfony 4.1](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing), and it's documented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test).

---

If the above for some reason doesn't work for you, you could create a `services_test.yaml` file and add this:

```yaml
# config/services_test.yaml

services:
    _defaults:
        public: true
```

... but this would only affect autowired services. If you need to access a services wired by a bundle, that service would remain private.

---

Finally, you could create a compiler pass to make all services public:

```php
class MakeServicesPublicPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        foreach ($container->getDefinitions() as $id => $definition) {
            $definition->setPublic(true);
        }

        foreach ($container->getAliases() as $id => $alias) {
            $alias->setPublic(true);
        }
    }
}
```

... and register this compiler pass only on your testing kernel.

---

Personally, I'd say the first option is the one to go, if possible in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you (a bit late), I'm actually using the `KernelTestCase`, together with `self::bootKernel()` then `self::getContainer()`, however I still cannot access a private service this way, and get *"The "(...)" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead."*

Comment: I can read in the `getContainer()` method description: *"The container will not include private services that have been inlined or removed."* They're probably inline in my case. So I'm afraid that the `KernelTestCase` still does not provide a way to make all services public? Do you see any other solution?